# Block that doesn't explicitly declare template?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout, blocks, template

I recently followed a tutorial to add a custom fee to the checkout summary of my Magento store and after getting everything working, I realized that the block I created didn't need to have an associated template when being added to various layout files, examples being sales_or_invoice_view and sales_guest_view, nor were the preferenced in module.xml.

I am curious why?

**sales_guest_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_totals">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Sales\Order\Fee" name="fee" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Fee.php**

```
class AdminFee extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var Order
     */
    protected $_order;
    /**
     * @return Order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->_order;
    }
    /**
     * Initialize all order totals relates with tax
     *
     * @return \Magento\Tax\Block\Sales\Order\Tax
     */
    public function initTotals()
    {
        $parent = $this->getParentBlock();
        $this->_order = $parent->getOrder();
        $fee = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'fee',
                'strong' => false,
                'value' => $this->_order->getFee(),
                'label' => __('Trial Fee'),
            ]
        );

        $parent->addTotal($fee, 'fee');
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the block you created doesn't need to have an associated template when being added to various layout files is because it is extending the `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` class, which provides a default template for the block. The template file that is being used is determined by the class name of the block and the location of the block's module, following a naming convention.

In your example, the block class is **"Vendor\Module\Block\Sales\Order\Fee"** which will look for a template file named **"fee.phtml"** in the `"Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/sales/order"` directory.

As for the preferences in module.xml, they are not necessary in this case because you are extending the `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` class directly in the Fee.php file. If you were extending a different class, then you would need to specify preferences in the module.xml file to ensure that Magento uses your custom class instead of the class that it would normally use.

Hope this help you to understand.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you. I had assumed it was due extending the template.

Comment: Where can I find the default template?